# Declaring Variables In Postgresql Queries ,NpgsqlCommand

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I convert from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

I used ADO.NET

My queries include defined variables inside the query

For example this

```cs
 SqlCommand sqlCommand=new SqlCommand(
                @"declare @tempId bigint 
                select top 1 @tempId = col1 from table 
                if @tempId is not null
                begin 
                select ...
                end 
                else 
                begin 
                select ...
                end ")
```

How do I do it with NpgsqlCommand?

Comment: SQL (the query language) doesn't support variables or an `IF` command and Postgres has no extension to the SQL language to support that. You will have to do that conditional logic in Ado.net or write a stored procedure using PL/pgSQL where variables and conditional execution is supported.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Is it possible to do this without Saved SP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PostgreSQL anonymous code DO block to execute a fragment of procedural code, [see the PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

Example:

```sql
DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables
             WHERE table_type = 'VIEW' AND table_schema = 'public'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON ' || quote_ident(r.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(r.table_name) || ' TO webuser';
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```